# RubyMine can't find Ruby SDK on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I'm trying to add Ruby SDK to RubyMine which is installed at `/snap/bin/ruby` however I get the following message.

```
Error configuring SDK: Could not get RubyGems environment for ruby-2.6.3-p62: ver.2.6.3p0 (/snap/bin/ruby).

Please make sure that /snap/bin/ruby is a valid home path for this SDK type.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please specify which RubyMine version you're using?

Comment: @Olivia ruby 2.6.3p62

Comment: Why did you accept the answer saying you should do what you seem to have already done? You've already pointed it to where you keep your Ruby binary file.

Comment: @BernhardBarker I understand your point. I have no idea now because it is almost a year.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, RubyMine cannot add Ruby installed using **snap**: [RUBY-23121](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-23121). As an alternative, you can install Ruby with **apt** or by using the [version manager](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/ruby-version-managers.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ruby installed via rbenv, then just select 2nd option 'New local version manager...', instead of 'New local...' since you are using rbenv. Your path should be like this: **/home/$USRNAME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv**.

Answer (score -1):

You should point it to the where you keep your Ruby Binary File, for example:

- Windows - d:\dev\Ruby19\bin\ruby.exe
- Mac Brew -/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
- Ruby Version Manager - /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
- Linux/Mac Default- /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question. `/snap/bin/ruby` is the location of the Ruby binary file. The asker has already pointed RubyMine there and gotten an error by doing so.